# Creating new columns in dataset as a lookup function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

so i lets say i have a datatable that consist of stock monthly returns:

| Company | Year | return | next years return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |  |

For a large dataset, of multiple companies and years how can i get a new column that consist of next years returns, for example in first row there would be second years return of 6% etc etc? In excel i could simple use index match but no idea how its done in R. And the reason for not using excel is that it takes over 20 hours to compute all functions as index match is extremely slow. The code needs to do this for all companies so it has to find the correct company for correct year and then input it into new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by the company and use `lead()` to get the next value:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
            company = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
               year = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L),
            return_ = c(5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L))
df 
#>   company year return_
#> 1       1    1       5
#> 2       1    2       6
#> 3       1    3       2
#> 4       1    4       4
#> 5       2    1       2
#> 6       2    2       4

df %>% group_by(company) %>%  
  mutate(next.years.return = lead(return_, order_by = year))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   company [2]
#>   company  year return_ next.years.return
#>     <int> <int>   <int>             <int>
#> 1       1     1       5                 6
#> 2       1     2       6                 2
#> 3       1     3       2                 4
#> 4       1     4       4                NA
#> 5       2     1       2                 4
#> 6       2     2       4                NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Getting the next years return if its really the next year.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  arrange(Company, Year) %>% 
  mutate("next years return" = 
    if_else(lead(Year) - Year == 1, lead(`return`), NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  Company  Year return `next years return`
    <dbl> <dbl>  <int>               <int>
1       1     1      5                  NA
2       1     3      2                   4
3       1     4      4                   6
4       1     5      6                  NA
5       2     1      5                   6
6       2     2      6                   2
7       2     3      2                   4
8       2     4      4                  NA
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Company = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Year = c(1, 
5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1), return = c(5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 
5L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "41", "31", "21", "11"
), class = "data.frame")
```